# Common Python libraries take 'forever' to import and some time-out

Tags: python, time, import, jupyter, libraries

Recently, something got messed up with my work computer (windows) and now importing external Python libraries takes very long.

**Problem description:**
I am able to run .py script files in CMD and VSCode normally if they don’t include importing any external libraries such as pandas and numpy etc. (standard libraries such as os and math are fine). However, if I try to run a simple test script with only, for example, “*import numpy as np*” in it, the execution takes almost two minutes. If I run the same script again, it finishes quickly, which I think has to do with the library being cached somewhere. Some libraries are even slower.. and as a weird example, Seaborn never even finishes its import, even when I've left the script running for 20 mins.

The slowness and occasional time-outs also happen when I try to run anything using a Jupyter notebook with Python kernel -- I get the error: “*Unable to start Kernel 'Python 3.11.6' due to a timeout waiting for the ports to get used.*”

**Attempted solutions:**

- Completely reinstalling Python, VSCode, and all Python libraries (twice)
- Resetting firewall settings and adding Python and VSCode as allowed programs
- Restarting pc and updating all programs
- Running everything as administrator

**Outcome:**
Imports are still slow and often time-out.

This is a very new problem, as all imports used to take little time (small modules measured in milliseconds and heavier modules in seconds). Now, importing, for example, the *numpy* and *pandas* libraries takes 3 minutes. Other programs on my computer are running fine, so I do not think it is a general performance issue.

Has anyone encountered anything like this before? Where should I look to investigate this further?

Our IT desk did not have any constructive ideas other than re-installing windows :D.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling windows and it solved the unidentifiable problem. Not really an answer to my post, but wanted to mention that the error is now fixed.